# How do I pass variables as column and table names in a python sqlite3 command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to pass a table name and a column name into a sqlite command in python. From what I understand, this can't be done through traditional methods.

```
conn.execute('ALTER TABLE ? ADD COLUMN ?;', t)
```

I've tried

```
{}.format

":X",(X: t)
```

and a few others, any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.format`:

```py
conn.execute('ALTER TABLE {} ADD COLUMN {};'.format(table, column))
```

or if you're using Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings:

```py
conn.execute(f'ALTER TABLE {table} ADD COLUMN {column};')
```